# Can't change background of div region using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This should be so simple, but I'm making heavy weather of it.

Div region set out as:

```
<div class="maincontent">
Stuff in my div
</div>
```

CSS for that div:

```
.maincontent{
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Then I have:

```
onLoad=changeBackground();
```

But before that I have the function:

```
function changeBackground(){
    document.getElementByAnything('maincontent').style.backgroundColor="yellow";    
}
```

I know its making the call to the function because if I put an alert box in there that shows. But no matter what combination of getElementBy I can't make any changes to the background?

Please help as its driving me insane!

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving your `div` an id and using `document.getElementById('divId')` instead? I think if you want to get the element by class you have to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

getElementById('maincontent')

and change your div to have an id="maincontent"

Comment: That would also require him to change the style from class to id.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the element an id and doing document.getElementById and then do console.log in firebug or other developer tools and verify that you are actually getting a dom element back.

Once you have verified that you should then be able to switch the background color

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select the div using its class. This isn't quite as straightforward as getting it by id. Try this:

```
<div class="maincontent" id='mainContent'>
Stuff in my div
</div>

function changeBackground(){
    document.getElementById('mainContent').style.backgroundColor="yellow";    
}
```

You can see a working example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPaKq/)

If you want to get the element using its class, I would recommend using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) or another library.

Comment: Careful when using caps in ID names. CSS doesn't always like it.

Comment: I've never heard that. Googling CSS standards returns results saying use either words-separated-by-dashes or standard camelCaseConvention.

Comment: Eh, I've had problems with it before on some browsers in the past (Safari in particular).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using in line Javascript then use, instead:

```
onchange="changeBackground(this)"
```

And:

```
function changeBackground(elem){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

---

**Edited** as I suddenly remembered you were discussing events based on `div` elements. As a `div` doesn't natively support the `onchange` event, I'd suggest amending your code to the following (though changing the event-type `onmouseover` to whatever event you find most appropriate):

```
function changeBackground(elem){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/99yR3/).

Also, to remove the events from in-line code, and to make the JavaScript more portable and less 'intrusive':

```
function changeBackground(elem){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

var maincontents = document.getElementsByClassName('maincontent');

for (var i=0,len=maincontents.length; i<len; i++){
    maincontents[i].onmouseover = function(){
        changeBackground(this);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/99yR3/1/).

Bear in mind, though, that some browsers ([such as Internet Explorer 8 and below](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11)) don't support `getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery if you want to select a DOM by class name.

Put this code in your <head> part of your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and change your function to

```
function changeBackground() {
    $(".maincontent").css("background-color","yellow");
}
```